# Firebase Funcions missing logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple function uploaded to Firebase Functions, that uses an external dependency (jimp). My code has some "console.log()" to trace what is happening when the function is triggered (by a 'write' action in Firstore).

According to the logs I can see in the firebase console,
[image]
every step of the function is running correctly, until it reaches the first call to the jimp object. At this point, no more logs on the console.

```
const Jimp  = require('jimp');
const os = require('os');
...
exports.manageImage2 = functions.firestore
    .document('/items/{docId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        console.info('event triggered:', event);
        console.log('tmpDir', os.tmpdir());
        const originalUrl = data.original_file_url;
        const imageSize = data.size;

        if (imageSize > maxSize) {
            console.log(`Image is too big (${imageSize})`);
            Jimp.read(originalUrl, (err, image) => {
 ...
```

I guess there is something wrong with the dependency, but I have no clue what it can be.

I obviously ran my code locally with any issue and also made sure the library is correctly listed in the dependencies of `package.json`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`Jimp.read` is a callback styled asynchronous function. Use promise for adapt it to functions.

```
exports.manageImage2 = functions.firestore
    .document('/items/{docId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        console.info('event triggered:', event);
        console.log('tmpDir', os.tmpdir());
        const originalUrl = data.original_file_url;
        const imageSize = data.size;

        if (imageSize > maxSize) {
            console.log(`Image is too big (${imageSize})`);
            return new Promise(resolve => Jimp.read(originalUrl, (err, image) => {
                // …
                // resolve(result);
            }));
        }
    });
```

For explanation read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions.